# Запуск bash из скрипта Python 2.7.3.

Tags: python, bash, linux

Всем привет! Есть такая проблема. Мне необходимо запустить из скрипта на Python, сценарий bash. Имею вот такой код питон-скрипта:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

def main():
    p = []
    p = os.popen("./test.sh 1")
    for line in p.readlines():
        print line
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

И такой вот простой bash, просто для примера... выводит последовательно числа в цикле.

```
#!/bin/bash
par=$1

for i in `seq $1 5`;
do
  echo $i 
done
```

Проблема в том, **что мне надо получать вывод скрипта bash сразу**. Т.е. не ждать когда он отработает. По мере поступления вывода, **надо делать определенные действия**.  Запуск bash скрипта стройкой кода:

```
p = os.popen("./test.sh 1")
```

Происходит превосходно! Но выполнение скрипта Python, останавливается до того так не отработает bash(((( Как это исправить?

p.s. Думаю я правильно поставил задачу и все меня поняли)))

Comment: Смотрите в сторону subprocess.Popen

Comment: Ладно, ладно. Ок. Вот что нашел - http://wiki.dieg.info/subprocess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой и близкий к вашему вариант - использовать не readlines(), а readline(). К сожалению, про for тогда придётся забыть и реализовывать это через while, если не хочется дописывать дополнительных нагромождений.

```
import os

def main():
    p = os.popen('./test.sh 1')
    line = True  # Любое не-False значение
    while line:
        line = p.readline()
        print line.strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Хотя по-хорошему, всё-таки, стоит использовать `subprocess`, т.к. он функциональней и вообще изначально создан, чтобы заменить os.popen:

```
The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several other, older modules and functions, such as:
os.system
os.spawn*
os.popen*
popen2.*
commands.*
```

(http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/subprocess.html)

Выглядеть это будет так:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['./test.sh', '1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
...
line = p.stdout.readline()
```

Всё остальное - абсолютно аналогично.

Для полной красоты можно обернуть это всё в функцию-генератор, чтобы вытаскивать всё `for`'ом, но это, во-первых, может быть оверкиллом, если подобные конструкции не встречаются часто (ну или хотя бы несколько раз) и, во-вторых, вообще другая тема.

Comment: не обязательно про `for`-цикл забывать: `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''): print line,`. See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)